# What to do with hacker attempts to guess my Admin Password and login in backend?

Tags: administrator, security

In all my Joomla sites, I find too many errors on the Logs/error.log like below:

> Joomla FAILURE:   Username and password do not match or you do not have
>   an account yet.

I think this indicates someone were trying my admin password. When thinking about the scale of the attempted attack, it feels very uncomfortable.
Shall I do anything about it?
What do you guys do?
And is blocking all the IPs in this list a good idea?

Comment: Why too broad this question guys? Maybe the title was (before editing), but then the question's content is describing a specific problem that can produce some useful and concise answers

Comment: Blocking the IPs is not efficient - not a good idea - unless you have a mechanism to create temporary blocks when X number of attacks has occurred. See answers below - and also search in JSE for security related questions like how to secure a Joomla site. You will find a lot of good ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the most simple thing you can do, is to put a username and password for your administrator folder in cpanel.

this way you should first input the username and password to see the Joomla login page.

Answer (score 3):

Joomla is a well known CMS and it's normally very easy to detect whether or not a site is powered by Joomla. Because of this, knowing the URL of the administrator page is easy to find.

With that in mind, you will always get people trying to brute force their way through.

I understand it would make you feel uncomfortable, so I'd suggest using Akeeba's [Login Guard](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/loginguard.html) extensions, which is similar to Joomla's Two Factor Authentication, but is has more features.

Akeeba's [Admin Tools](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/admin-tools.html) is also another great extension that comes with some very handy features to add extra security layers to you site

Answer (score 2):

Add password protection to the admin folder through cpanel and enable two factor authentication on the site then on your superuser acct.  After that, no need to feel uncomfortable.  Far leaner solution than installing any extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an existing Joomla! extension that can identify [brute-force-attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) and attempt to stop it, for example:

https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/brute-force-stop/

OR

Perhaps code your own version of it!

*Note that I have no experience whatsoever in the use of such extensions. I just happened to know what to look for. Happy upgrading!*